# How do you check if you are writing a new method or override existing one?

Tags: c++, overriding

I mean, if I'm inside my class B that extend some other class A (not created by me), how would you know that the method you are writing:

```
void SetStatus() { }
```

it's not already declared and you are just override it? Right click->Go to Definition every time? (on VS2015 for example).

Comment: besides some sort of static analyzation I do not think there is a language feature that will work for all cases.

Comment: I'm not a user of VS, but in Eclipse CDT there's an indicator in the left margin of the editor that appears if a member function overrides or shadows a base class function. Might VS have something similar?

Comment: @FredLarson no, VS doesn't have anything similar.

Comment: Are you interested in detecting _override_ only or you are also interested in _shadowing_?

Comment: Read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the code - you could declare the method `final` in your base class, then the code won't compile if you try to override a virtual method.

If you want to be able to override it, you could try to call A::SetStatus(); in the definition of B::SetStatus().

If your IDE Displays an error and it doesn't compile, then it's not implemented in A.
This is quite similar to the "Goto definition" approach though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [override specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) (since C++11), such as:

```
void SetStatus() override { }
```

What you expect is to get a compile error. If you get it, means the function (i.e. `SetStatus()` here) is not declared or it's declared but the signature doesn't match. Then you can confirm that there's no overriding and remove `override specifier`.

Comment: I think the "Right click->Go to Definition" the OP mentions would be easier.